# Visual Basic ByRef integer

Tags: vb.net, pointers

How do you make an integer, but instead of setting it a value, setting it a reference to the value of another variable?

Comment: Why would you need to? And I would like to quote from the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.".

Comment: Are you trying to do this just because you're used to using pointers in C, and you just haven't learned how to do it right in .NET yet, or are you really needing to do it this way as your only option?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply nonsense. The reference which is an address to a location in memory takes up same place as an integer value does, on 32 bit. And even less than the the address on 64 bit.

You better stick to the variable itself unless you want to pass the pointer to an API or something.

Answer (score 0):

Using an integer as a pointer was sometimes necessary in VB6 in order to call system functions, but the need and the ability to use an integer as a pointer is no longer in vb.net.

If you need to use an address in vb.net, you can use `AddressOf` for functions, and `InPtr` for unmanaged memory. However, there's a good chance you don't really need to do this -- it's relatively uncommon.

Comment: How do I use them to do what I asked?

Comment: @user1628: You can't? Thats what the two answers told you? Maybe you update your question and tell us, WHAT you want to do and not HOW (you believe) you would like to "solve" your problem?

Comment: Here's some info on AddressOf and InPtr:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1